# How do I tell Google Chrome to read a different hosts file?

Tags: google-chrome, hosts-file

At work in my university, the computers in the office all use Windows XP, latest service pack. They've given each one of us a regular account, with no way of installing programs or making system-relevant changes. They have blocked many websites (YouTube, proxy sites, Facebook, etc.) simply by adding an entry for each one of them in hosts file, such as

```
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.metacafe.com
127.0.0.1 metacafe.com
```

etc.

If I could simply tell Google Chrome to use a hosts file stored somewhere else then that would be it. I *did* read [question 343158](https://superuser.com/questions/343158/is-there-a-chrome-extension-that-simulates-manipulation-of-the-etc-hosts-file), but I can't set an HTTP server because of limited privileges on the machine.

As I could notice after reading the first answer, I needed to further detail my question, so here it goes: I have already circumvented DNS blocking in the past (the usual way) by first checking the IP address of a certain website at [pages like this one](http://www.selfseo.com/find_ip_address_of_a_website.php) and then I added the corresponding entry to the hosts file on my own computer, much like the following

```
92.123.66.131 www.metacafe.com
72.32.120.222 metacafe.com
```

and it has always worked for me thus far. For any site. However, this is a different case: I don't have write access to the hosts file, I can't install software, and I can't do pretty much anything that bears significance. I installed the portable version of Google Chrome because the computer only had IE, so I am looking for a way to make Google Chrome read a hosts file from a custom location, so I could build my own file (or perhaps copy the one I have on my laptop) and browse on top of that one.

Comment: You may have read the question, but you didn't read my answer.  Nowhere did I specify that the HTTP proxy has to be installed and running on the same machine as the WWW browser.  (I myself have single HTTP proxies serving entire LANs.)  On the gripping hand, I recommend _not_ trying to evade administrative restrictions for preventing non-work use on machines that you don't own, and _not_ setting up or using promiscuous proxy HTTP servers outwith your LAN and accessible to the public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When they block something, I would advise you to not try to circumvent it.

It might be that it's impossible to visit it by IP given that it could automatically redirect to the domain name.

1. You could try to remember its IP http://66.220.149.11 or its [long](http://www.elfqrin.com/LongIP.html) IP http://1121752331
2. You could use an easy to remember URL, like: http://tiny.cc/f4c3b00k
3. Browse Facebook through some kind of proxy, which should always work.

Again, I advise against this. You really don't want to work around their policies, they might monitor it...

You can probably figure out the same for metacafe, start with a `ping metacafe.com`.

Comment: Facebook redirects to its dns name once you access by IP, so would still hit the hostname issue.

Comment: @TomWijsman I can't use the IP in the address bar because it doesn't work for sites like YouTube. I'll edit the question now to add some more details.

Comment: @the.midget: Well, then you'll either need an online proxy or a portable proxy like [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), I don't know if it is capable of rewriting requests such that the IP is changed though.

Comment: @TomWijsman Ok, I'll give Privoxy a try...

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

Access restricted web sites using Google language tools service as a proxy

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/h/4807

;-)

Comment: This wouldn't be practical for sites you need to log into and do anything other than mere page browsing, right?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use portable Firefox and the [SwitchHosts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchhosts/) addon?

Comment: I only can use Chrome here. Can't install anything. +1 though for... don't know why.

Comment: I suppose I'm confused.  Portable Firefox means you run it off a flash drive, not installing anything.

Comment: It is I that was confused. Sorry. I read it in a hustle and apparently skipped the word "portable". My problem is now solved now, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the host file by booting into a Linux CD or USB, which can circumvent the windows access-restriction system.

Comment: Great idea, but the computer's BIOS is password-protected, and does not allow for disc-booting. I couldn't possibly open the computer up, you see. If they got me for that... However, +1 for creativity (I never would've thought about this, in spite of being a hard-core Linux user)